# Ruby regular expression suggestion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Hi I have a string,

```
<p style="margin:0pt; orphans:0; widows:0"><img src="asset/image/3/image.001.jpeg" width="333" height="166" alt="" data-np-asset-type="Image" data-np-asset-id="3" data-np-asset-target="src"/><p>some big paragraph</p>
```

I need modify the image src path from **asset/image/3/image.001.jpeg** to **asset/image/19/image.001.jpeg** and **data-np-asset-id="3"** to **data-np-asset-id="19"**

Comment: How are you extracting the span from its HTML page?

Comment: The entire html is stored in the table as a string. so i have it.

Comment: Are you making more than one replacement? Are there other replacements to do of the same type? I'm trying to determine if you'd be better off with an HTML parser like Nokogiri.

Comment: yes there are about few 100 records that would need this change. The reason behind this madness is we are merging datas from two diff system and the image ids conflict. so we recreated the ids but the reference to the id is hard coded inside the database columns and that needs to be changed as well

Comment: Remove everything from your sample HTML that is not essential to answering your question. Then format it so it's readable. As is you discourage people from answering your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
html = %{<span style="font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:1.08em; font-weight:bold">Birbal identifies the thief</span></p></td></tr><tr><td style="padding-left:5.4pt; padding-right:5.4pt; vertical-align:middle; width:382pt"><p style="margin:0pt; orphans:0; widows:0"><img src="asset/image/3/image.001.jpeg" width="333" height="166" alt="" data-np-asset-type="Image" data-np-asset-id="3" data-np-asset-target="src"/><p>some big paragraph</p>}

html.gsub!(/"3"/, "\"9\"").gsub!(/\/3\//, "/9/")
#=> "<span style=\"font-family:Verdana, sans-serif; font-size:1.08em; font-weight:bold\">Birbal identifies the thief</span></p></td></tr><tr><td style=\"padding-left:5.4pt; padding-right:5.4pt; vertical-align:middle; width:382pt\"><p style=\"margin:0pt; orphans:0; widows:0\"><img src=\"asset/image/9/image.001.jpeg\" width=\"333\" height=\"166\" alt=\"\" data-np-asset-type=\"Image\" data-np-asset-id=\"9\" data-np-asset-target=\"src\"/><p>some big paragraph</p>"
```